# How can I save a spark dataframe as a partition of a partitioned hive table

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive

how to save a spark dataframe into one partition of a partitioned hive table?

```
raw_nginx_log_df.write.saveAsTable("raw_nginx_log")
```

the above way could overwrite the whole table but not a specific partition.
although i can solve the problem by the following code , it is obviously not elegant.

```
raw_nginx_log_df.registerTempTable("tmp_table")
sql(s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE raw_nginx_log PARTITION (par= '$PARTITION_VAR')")
```

it seems that in stackoverflowc.com there is no  similar questions asked ever before!

Comment: `raw_nginx_log_df.write.partitionBy("partition_col").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("raw_nginx_log")`

Comment: what if raw_nginx_log_df2 need to by saved into another partition of the table ?

Comment: *"not elegant"* is a matter of personal taste *(for instance, Scala makes me puke)* -- the question is, does it work? Does it make any difference performance-wise? If you are not satisfied, can you contribute a patch to the Spark code base?

Comment: here is the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method

Answer (score 2):

```
YourDataFrame.write.format("parquet").option("/pathHiveLocation").mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("partitionCol").saveAsTable("YourTable")
```

For parquet files/tables. You may customize it as per your requirement.