# How can I append to same file in HDFS(spark 2.11)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to store Stream Data into  HDFS using SparkStreaming,but it Keep creating in ***new file*** insted of appending into one single file or few multiple files

If it keep creating n numbers of files,i feel it won't be much efficient

***HDFS FILE SYSYTEM***
[image]

***Code***

```
lines.foreachRDD(f => {
  if (!f.isEmpty()) {
    val df = f.toDF().coalesce(1)
    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json("hdfs://localhost:9000/MT9")
  }
 })
```

In my pom I am using respective dependencies:

- spark-core_2.11
- spark-sql_2.11
- spark-streaming_2.11
- spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11

Comment: If you're reading data from Kafka into HDFS, I suggest you look at using Nifi or Kafka Connect. Don't rewrite code for existing solutions

Comment: hdfs is meant to be write once and read many times,you cannot be able to write to same file .in order to do that you had to do compaction kind of process which hive and hbase follows

Answer (score 6):

As you already realized `Append` in Spark  means write-to-existing-directory not append-to-file.

This is intentional and desired behavior (think what would happen if process failed in the middle of "appending" even if format and file system allow that).

Operations like merging files should be applied by a separate process, if necessary at all, which ensures correctness and fault tolerance. Unfortunately this requires a full copy which, for obvious reasons is not desired on batch-to-batch basis.

Comment: you can go through this link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html


Append mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, contents of the DataFrame are expected to be appended to existing data.

Comment: @andani That's appending in Spark... For HDFS, appending means adding new files into a directory rather than overwriting that directory completely

Comment: @cricket_007 then is their any way to store data in same file as it is their in Storm

Comment: @andani I have never used Storm, but I known it isn't used for persistent data storage

Comment: @cricket_007 what i ment to say is their built in libraries which stores data in hdfs in required fashion.

Comment: @andani HDFS is considered an append-only file system. I don't really understand what you're trying to do otherwise, but if you only want one file, then coalesce immediately rather than looping over foreachRDD

Comment: @cricket_007 what you said is right ,what i am trying to do similar to this problem statement :https://stackoverflow.com/q/44492558/7527189   which is next part of  it.

Comment: @andani What you want linked to uses parquet, which might support appends. You're using JSON

Comment: `Append mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, contents of the DataFrame are expected to be appended to existing data.` - This is what the docs state about `append`. I would never have come to the conclusion from this that this means that the original data is not touched. Do you have any source where there is more information on the "real" append behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

It’s creating file for each rdd as every time you are reinitialising the DataFrame variable. I would suggest have a DataFrame variable and assign as null outside of loop and inside each rdd union with the local DataFrame. After the loop write using the outer DataFrame.

Comment: still the same case

Comment: var empty = sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
     lines.foreachRDD(f => {
      if (!f.isEmpty()) {
        empty = f.toDF().coalesce(1)
          empty.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json(warehouseLocation)
      }
    })

Comment: Inside your condition add this if(empty == null) empty = f.toDF() else empty = empty.union(f.toDF()) after the loop ends empty.coalesce(1).write.mode rest your option. Please do not write it inside the loop

Comment: df doesnot have fiexd no. coloum, so getting error for your condition.