# Cannot save spark dataframe as CSV

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am attempting to save a Spark DataFrame as a CSV. I have looked up numerous different posts and guides and am, for some reason, still getting an issue. The code I am using to do this is

```
endframe.coalesce(1).
      write.
      mode("append").
      csv("file:///home/X/Code/output/output.csv")
```

I have also tried this by including `.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")` as well as by changing the .csv() to a .save() and strangely none of these work. The most unusual part is that running this code creates an empty folder called "output.csv" in the output folder.
The error message that spark gives is

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 281.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.3 in stage 281.0 (TID 22683, X.x.local, executor 4): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Task failed while writing rows.
```

I have verified that the dataframe schema is properly initialized. However, when I use the .format, I do not import com.databricks.spark.csv, but I do not think that is the problem. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

The schema is as follows:

```
 |-- kwh: double (nullable = true)
 |-- qh_end: double (nullable = true)
 |-- cdh70: double (nullable = true)
 |-- norm_hbu: double (nullable = true)
 |-- precool_counterprecoolevent_id6: double (nullable = true)
 |-- precool_counterprecoolevent_id7: double (nullable = true)
 |-- precool_counterprecoolevent_id8: double (nullable = true)
 |-- precool_counterprecoolevent_id9: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id10event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id2event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id3event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id4event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id5event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id6event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id7event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id8event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id9event_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_idTestevent_counterevent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id10snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id2snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id3snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id4snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id5snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id6snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id7snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id8snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id9snapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event_idTestsnapback_countersnapback: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: As far as I know, mode `APPEND` in Spark does mean _**append to an existing directory**_, not _append to a file_. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020799/how-can-i-append-to-same-file-in-hdfsspark-2-11) help you.

Comment: Can you provide the schema of the dataframe as well? It looks like an issue with the schema to me.

Comment: @PraveenNag It's there now

Comment: @ulubeyn I do not believe I am saving to HDFS, so I think in this case, it should be appending to a file. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html)

Comment: @Cheezbeez the schema looks fine. on the other note, i believe irrespective of file system, it will create a directory (if the directory isn't available else it will simply append the file) due to it's distributed nature. Just a wild guess: this failure could be due to permission/less space in the file system if it's not hdfs.

Comment: @Cheezbeez is the coalesce overloading the driver's memory? Does it write when you don't use coalesce?

Comment: Interestingly, the code writes to HDFS by creating a folder by the name of output.csv and writing to it. I do not know why it wasn't able to write to the file system but the problem is sort of solved now.