# overwrite hive partitions using spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am working with AWS and I have workflows that use Spark and Hive. My data is partitioned by the date, so everyday I have a new partition in my S3 storage.
My problem is when one day the load data fails and I have to re-execute that partition. The code that writes is next:

```
df                            // My data in a Dataframe
  .write
  .format(getFormat(target))  // csv by default, but could be parquet, ORC...
  .mode(getSaveMode("overwrite"))  // Append by default, but in future it should be Overwrite
  .partitionBy(partitionName) // Column of the partition, the date
  .options(target.options)    // header, separator...
  .option("path", target.path) // the path where it will be storage
  .saveAsTable(target.tableName)  // the table name
```

What happens in my flow? If I use the SaveMode.Overwrite, the complete table will be delete and I will have only the partition saved. If I use the SaveMode.Append I could have duplicate data.

Making a search, I found that Hive support this kind of overwrite, only partition, but using the hql sentences, I don´t have it.

We need the solution on Hive, so we can´t use this [alternative option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method) (direct to csv).

I had found this [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20236) that suppose to solve the problem that I´m having, but trying that with the last version of Spark (2.3.0), the situation was the same. It delete the whole table and save the partition instead of overwrite the partition that my data has.

Trying to make clearer this, this is an example:

Partitioned by A

Data:

```
| A | B | C | 
|---|---|---| 
| b | 1 | 2 | 
| c | 1 | 2 |
```

Table:

```
| A | B | C | 
|---|---|---| 
| a | 1 | 2 | 
| b | 5 | 2 |
```

What I want is: In Table, the partition `a` stay in table, partition `b` overwrite with the Data, and add the partition `c`. Is there any solution using Spark that I can do this?

My last option to do this is first deleting the partition that is going to be saved and then use the SaveMode.Append, but I would try this in case there is no other solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are on Spark 2.3.0, try setting `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` setting to `dynamic`, the dataset needs to be partitioned, and the write mode overwrite.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
data.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("partitioned_table")
```

Comment: This is so usefull, thanks. But I am using actually Spark 2.2.1, so I can´t use it now but in future, when upgrade Spark to 2.3.0 I use this.

Comment: I am happy that you found it useful.

Comment: This is not working with spark 2.4.0 and I am getting duplicates with above code. Any thoughts ?

Comment: will this work on a managed table with `.saveAsTable(...)`

Comment: @ChitralVerma it doesn't work for me. saveAsTable deletes all the data anyway.

Comment: can you give me some more details about your setup ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to run sql using sparksession. you can run " insert overwrite partition query" by selecting the columns from existing dataset. this solution will surely overwrites partition only.

Comment: This is deleting my entire table though , as stated in original problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you are using Spark version < 2.3 and want to write into partitions dynamically without deleting the others, you can implement the below solution.

The idea is to register the dataset as a table and then use spark.sql() to run the INSERT query.

```
// Create SparkSession with Hive dynamic partitioning enabled
val spark: SparkSession =
    SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("StatsAnalyzer")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
        .getOrCreate()
// Register the dataframe as a Hive table
impressionsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("impressions_dataframe")
// Create the output Hive table
spark.sql(
    s"""
      |CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE stats (
      |   ad            STRING,
      |   impressions   INT,
      |   clicks        INT
      |) PARTITIONED BY (country STRING, year INT, month INT, day INT)
      |ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    """.stripMargin
)
// Write the data into disk as Hive partitions
spark.sql(
    s"""
      |INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE stats 
      |PARTITION(country = 'US', year = 2017, month = 3, day)
      |SELECT ad, SUM(impressions), SUM(clicks), day
      |FROM impressions_dataframe
      |GROUP BY ad
    """.stripMargin
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what wandermonk@ mentioned,

---

Dynamic Partition Inserts is only supported in SQL mode (for INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE SQL statements). Dynamic Partition Inserts is not supported for non-file-based data sources, i.e. InsertableRelations.

With Dynamic Partition Inserts, the behaviour of OVERWRITE keyword is controlled by spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode configuration property (default: static). The property controls whether Spark should delete all the partitions that match the partition specification regardless of whether there is data to be written to or not (static) or delete only those partitions that will have data written into (dynamic).

When the dynamic overwrite mode is enabled Spark will only delete the partitions for which it has data to be written to. All the other partitions remain intact.

From

From the Writing Into Dynamic Partitions Using Spark (https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/spark-dynamic-partition-inserts-part-1-5b66a145974f)

---

Spark now writes data partitioned just as Hive would — which means only the partitions that are touched by the INSERT query get overwritten and the others are not touched.