# Overwrite only some partitions in a partitioned spark Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-dataset

How can we overwrite a partitioned dataset, but only the partitions we are going to change? For example, recomputing last week daily job, and only overwriting last week of data.

Default Spark behaviour is to overwrite the whole table, even if only some partitions are going to be written.

Comment: Before Spark 2.3.0 there is a JIRA created for this. In 2.3.0 this is fixed. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20236

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Since Spark 2.3.0 this is an option when overwriting a table. To overwrite it, you need to set the new `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` setting to `dynamic`, the dataset needs to be partitioned, and the write mode `overwrite`.
Example **in scala**:

```scala
spark.conf.set(
  "spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic"
)
data.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("partitioned_table")
```

I recommend doing a repartition based on your partition column before writing, so you won't end up with 400 files per folder.

Before Spark 2.3.0, the best solution would be to launch SQL statements to delete those partitions and then write them with mode append.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but didn't work for me. I had to pass in the overwrite=True as an argument in the insertInto method
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto
But thanks for the clue, this rocks

Comment: Doesn't work with `insertInto` but works perfectly with `save.`

Comment: @MadhavaCarrillo Hi, are you aware of a setting to only delete the partition, instead of replacing it? Thanks

Comment: @cph_sto not really, no. You can use the drop partition from hive. `alter table t1 drop if exists partition (p1=1);` or even using comparators like `alter table t drop partition (PARTITION_COL>1);`

Comment: @neerajbhadani you can use those in hive, in a hive CLI.

Comment: @suhprano I experienced that in python, not in Scala.

Comment: @MadhavaCarrillo Hi, Many thanks for confirming it. Actually, I has posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520227/how-to-delete-a-particular-month-from-a-parquet-file-partitioned-by-month) and someone answered with a similar answer, but I am using `external tables` and not `internal tables `. In addition to that, I am not on HIVE, instead I am using `Jupyter-PySpark`. I don't know how to do it there.

Comment: Note that your target table format has to support dynamic partitioning. If it does not and you apply the steps above, be aware that your table might be deleted! Learned that the hard way, even though I luckily made a backup before

Answer (score 23):

Just FYI, for PySpark users make sure to set `overwrite=True` in the `insertInto` otherwise the mode would be changed to `append`

from the [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html#DataFrameWriter.insertInto):

```
def insertInto(self, tableName, overwrite=False):
    self._jwrite.mode(
        "overwrite" if overwrite else "append"
    ).insertInto(tableName)
```

this how to use it:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","DYNAMIC")
data.write.insertInto("partitioned_table", overwrite=True)
```

or in the SQL version works fine.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE [db_name.]table_name [PARTITION part_spec] select_statement
```

[for doc look at here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/insert.html)

Answer (score 1):

This works also for me, since is easier and straighforward

> ```
> df.write.partitionBy('dt').mode('overwrite').format('parquet').option(
> "partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").save(path)
> ```

**Source**: https://kontext.tech/article/1067/spark-dynamic-and-static-partition-overwrite