# What is the difference between saveAasTable and save in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using Pyspark and want to insert-overwrite partitions into a existing hive table.

- in this use case `saveAsTable()` is not suitable, it overwrites the whole existing table
- `insertInto()` is behaving strangely: I have 3 partition levels, but it is inserting one

Snd what is the right way to use `save()`?
Can `save()` take options like database-name and table name to insert into, or only HDFS path?

example :

```
df\
.write\
.format('orc')\
.mode('overwrite)\
.option('database', db_name)\
.option('table', table_name)\
.save()
```

Comment: What about [Overwrite specific partitions in spark dataframe write method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method) ?