# Overwrite specific CSV partitions pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe named `df`, which is partitioned on the column `date`. I need to save on S3 this dataframe with the CSV format. When I write the dataframe, I need to delete the partitions (i.e. the dates) on S3 for which the dataframe has data to be written to. All the other partitions need to remain intact.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method/38576659#38576659) that this is exactly the job of the option `spark.sql.sources.partitionoverwritemode` set to `dynamic`.

However, it does not seem to work for me with CSV files.
If I use it on parquet with the following command it works perfectly:

```
df.write
.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
.partitionBy("date")
.format("parquet")
.mode("overwrite")
.save(output_dir)
```

But if I use it on CSV with the following command it does not work:

```
df.write
.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
.partitionBy("date")
.format("csv")
.mode("overwrite")
.save(output_dir)
```

Why is this the case? Any idea of how this behaviour could be implemented with CSV outputs?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to delete the partitions (i.e. the dates) on S3 for which the dataframe has data to be written to

Assuming you have a convenient list of the dates you are processing you can use the `replaceWhere` option to determine the partitions to overwrite (delete and replace).

For example:

```py
df.write
.partitionBy("date")
.option("replaceWhere", "date >= '2020-12-14' AND date <= '2020-12-15'")
.format("csv")
.mode("overwrite")
.save(output_dir)
```

---

A more dynamic way is if you have the `start_date` and `end_date` stored in variables:

```py
start_date = "2022-01-01"
end_date = "2022-01-14"

condition = f"date >= '{start_date}' AND date <= '{end_date}'"

df.write
.partitionBy("date")
.option("replaceWhere", condition)
.format("csv")
.mode("overwrite")
.save(output_dir)
```

Comment: I guess this also works with a list of dates placed in OR conditions. However, do you think there is any limitation with respect to the maximum number of dates? I.e. if I have 1000 separated dates with OR conditions do you think there is any perfomance limitations?

Comment: There might be a limit, yes. If you share how you have these dates stored (e.g in `val`'s I can update my answer with the best way I know of as to how to incorporate them into the `replaceWhere`.

Comment: I just tried to add the condition but unfortunately it does not work. All the remaining partitions (which should not be touched by the condition) are deleted. Any help?

Comment: Can you update your question with your updated query? I'll be able to update my answer accordingly from this.

Answer (score 0):

What Spark version do you use? For Spark <2.0.0 it may seem impossible to use partitioning along with the csv format

Comment: I am on spark 3.2.1. I saw that "spark.sql.sources.partitionoverwritemode" works from 2.3.0, but not for CSV file formats apparently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on EMR, and are using the s3a committers to safely commit work to s3, then the [partitioned committer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html#The_.E2.80.9CPartitioned.E2.80.9D_Staging_Committer) can be set to delete all data in the destination partitions before committing new work, leaving all other partitions alone.

Comment: If I use "replace" with .option("fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode", "replace") but it does not seem to work. The partitions which should be untouched are deleted.