# How to read certain parquet file partitions using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Is it possible to read certain partitions from a folder using spark?

I only know this way:
df = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/Staging/file_Name/")

Is there any way to read only those partitions where the date is not less than today minus 3 months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your dataframe is partitioned by date, you can just use filter, spark will read only partitions with this date

`df = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/Staging/file_Name/").filter(col("your_date_col") === "2022-02-03")`

Comment: do you know any way how I can overwrite certain partitions in a folder, and leave other partitions unchanged?

Comment: @Denis if you have spark 2.3+  than you can use dynamic partitioning 
[overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method)