# Do you know any way how I can overwrite certain partitions in a folder, and leave other partitions unchanged?

Tags: apache-spark

do you know any way how I can overwrite certain partitions in a folder, and leave other partitions unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe contains only data from the partitions you would like to overwrite then you need to set `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` to `dynamic` (Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method) as well).