# How do I update part of a dataset without doing a snapshot build of the whole dataset?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

We have datasets partitioned on date, with a history going back some arbitrary amount of time.

If we need to apply updates to a particular day's data, we'd ideally want to replace *just* that day's data with new data, and leave data for all other days unchanged.

In Spark, this seems to be possible with `partitionOverwriteMode` (see [Overwrite specific partitions in spark dataframe write method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method))

In the Foundry documentation of Snapshot vs. Incremental builds, there is no mention of updating datasets - it seems to only address appending to datasets via Incremental.

Comment: Assuming that your dataset is incremental, I am not aware of a solution without breaking the incremental computation. This seems to be a limitation of the Foundry Catalog. You could identify the parquet file + transaction which contains the row that you want to update and rewrite this file and perform a manual UPDATE transaction overwriting the single file. However, to my knowledge this will break your incremental...