# partitionOverwriteMode not working when set through dataframe option for insertInto

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Suppose I have an existing dataframe that is partitioned by a column and the file format for storage is parquet. I know that to update specific partitions, I need to use `partitionOverwriteMode`. The problem is that if I set the above using `spark.conf.set('partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')`, it works. But when I set it using

```py
df.write.mode('overwrite').option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").insertInto('db1.t1')
```

It doesn't work. It doesn't delete the partition folders, but removes all the data from them and only keeps the data for the partition fitting for the current dataframe.

I know that I can make it work by using spark.conf.set. I want to know why it is not working this way. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Azure Databricks with the 13.3 LTS version, Spark version 3.4.1.

Comment: which version of pyspark is this ?

Comment: 3.4.1. I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

seems like the order of writing the code is different

Can you try this? It should work use write.option like below

```
 
df.write.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partitionColumn").save("output.parquet")
```

`insertInto` might not be working with `partitionOverwriteMode` because of limitations in certain data sources. While Spark SQL supports the `partitionOverwriteMode` option for various data sources like Parquet and ORC, some data sources, like Hive tables managed by `insertInto`, might have their own overwrite behavior and might not recognize this configuration directly.

consider using `df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partitionColumn").saveAsTable("db1.t1")`. This approach bypasses `insertInto` and might work better with `partitionOverwriteMode`.

Comment: I am using the `insertInto` command. I changed the sequence and ran the following command `df.write.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").mode('overwrite').insertInto('db1.t1')`. But it didn't work

Comment: Hey, I cannot replace `insertInto` with `saveAsTable` because the latter creates a new table with the `overwrite` mode. And I cannot use `append` mode with `saveAsTable` because then it does not overwrite a partition.

Comment: Also, my interest is in knowing why the `insertInto` and `partitionOverwriteMode` don't work. As you have given some points about the problem being related to data sources, could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following approaches:

**1st Approach:**

```
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS partitioned_table (
    Name STRING,
    PartitionColumn STRING,
    Age INT
)
USING delta
PARTITIONED BY (PartitionColumn)
""")
df.write.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").mode("overwrite").format("delta").partitionBy("PartitionColumn").saveAsTable("partitioned_table")
```

In the above approach, partition overwrite mode is set to "dynamic".
In Delta Lake, dynamic partition overwrite mode allows you to overwrite a partition without affecting the data in other partitions.

The write mode is "overwrite", which means that if the table already exists, it will be replaced with the new data.

saveAsTable("partitioned_table") saves the DataFrame as a table named "partitioned_table".

**2nd approach:**

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS partitioned_table1 (
    Name STRING,
    PartitionColumn STRING,
    Age INT
)
USING delta
PARTITIONED BY (PartitionColumn)
""")
df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("partitioned_table1")
```

**Results:**

select * from partitioned_table

```
Name    PartitionColumn    Age
Charlie    Partition1    35
Arthur    Partition2    30
Fin    Partition2    40
Tom    Partition1    25
```

select * from partitioned_table1

```
Name    PartitionColumn    Age
Charlie    Partition1    35
Arthur    Partition2    30
Fin    Partition2    40
Tom    Partition1    25
```

**Reference:** [Overwrite specific partitions in spark dataframe write method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487667/overwrite-specific-partitions-in-spark-dataframe-write-method)

Comment: Have you tried using the insertinto command with a dataframe already having some data. Does it delete the data  and replace it with the new one? Or does it only replace the data for the specific partition?

Comment: Yes I have tried using the insertinto command with a dataframe already having some data.

Comment: My code fails when I use `insertinto` and set the dynamic option with the write API and not using spark.conf.set. Can you tell why is that?